# How to turn off Phone Equalizer programmatically?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-music-player

I have two buttons, one opens phone's default equalizer and one opens my app specific Audio Effects (Reverb, BassBoost and Virtualizer). Whenever the default equalizer is ON, and i open app-specific audioeffects activity, App crashes.

Logcat of the error is attached below.

```
com.widefide.musicplayer/com.widefide.musicplayer.EqualizerActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation
        at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.checkStatus(AudioEffect.java:1273)
        at android.media.audiofx.Virtualizer.setStrength(Virtualizer.java:153)
        at com.widefide.musicplayer.MusicService.setVirtualizerStrength(MusicService.java:571)
        at com.widefide.musicplayer.EqualizerActivity.setVirtualizerStrength(EqualizerActivity.java:65)
        at com.widefide.musicplayer.Fragments.EQ.FXFragment.onProgressChanged(FXFragment.java:183)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:93)
        at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:1303)
        at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:1315)
        at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:1466)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:339)
        at com.widefide.musicplayer.Fragments.EQ.FXFragment.onActivityCreated(FXFragment.java:87)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1983)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2046)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:174)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:598)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Now, I want to turn off Phone's equalizer programmatically when I open audioEffects activity through Intent. Code would follow like this:

```
// Before opening FX, turn Equalizer OFF
    .. EQ OFF code here ...    
// FX
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FX.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Has stackoverflow become "Go find answer yourself"?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I have the same one.